# how to alter a Query and join with another table in views 3.0 drupal 7.x?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to alter a view and join it with taxonomy_index table but it seems that this code does not work

```
function MY_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
$view->query->add_relationship('my_join', new views_join('taxonomy_index', 'nid', 'node', 'nid','INNER'), 'taxonomy_index');
$view->query->add_where('country_price', "my_join.tid IN ", '2,3');
}
```

how can I join this view's query with the taxonomy_index table?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to use hook_query_alter instead of hook_views_query_alter. I have only done this with an Equals in the where clause, but I'm assuming 'IN' will work the same.

```
function MY_MODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasAllTags('views', '[MY VIEW NAME]')) {
    $query->addJoin('INNER', 'taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'node.nid = ti.nid');
    $query->condition('ti.tid', '2,3', 'IN');
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work as "addJoin" is not defined as method of "views_plugin_query_default"